# Pacman Full system upgrade ask for replacing packages

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

Every time I do a full system upgrade pacman ask me the same question :

```
tarting full system upgrade...
:: Replace mga-dri with extra/libgl? [Y/n] n
:: Replace r128-dri with extra/libgl? [Y/n] n
:: Replace sis-dri with extra/libgl? [Y/n] n
:: Replace tdfx-dri with extra/libgl? [Y/n] n
```

and everytime I click no.

It's some kind of annoying.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should blacklist the packages in question. Edit your `/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
IgnorePkg = mga-dri r128-dri sis-dri tdfx-dri
```

This way `pacman` will not try to upgrade these packages as long as they're blacklisted.

Comment: Please note that keeping package no longer supported will possible lead to non-supported breakage.